# Probability on selecting balls

Tags: probability

> If I have B black balls and W white balls in a bag, what is the probability that the last one I select is white?

How shall I solve this problem?

I am not sure how to make a start, is it correct to first assume $B \lt W$?

Comment: Why should *B < W* ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Here's a similar, slightly easier question:  What's the probability that the *first* ball you select is white?

Comment: Start with "It is obvious that $\dots$."

Comment: It depends on how you decide to stop selecting balls. If you stop as soon as you choose a white one, the probability is greatly increased. I suspect you actually intended to pull out all the balls until there are none left; but if that is true then you should say so in the text of the question.

Comment: Can you determine the probability that the first picked ball is white? And what about the probability the second ball is white (despite the color of the first one)? And the probability that the N-th picked ball is white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways to select the balls is $(B+W)!$

The number of ways to select the balls with the last one being white is $(B+W-1)!\cdot{W}$

Hence the probability that the last ball selected is white is $\dfrac{(B+W-1)!\cdot{W}}{(B+W)!}=\dfrac{W}{B+W}$

Answer (score 1):

The insight that you can carry is that **colored balls (or, say, cards) have no preference for position**.

With this insight, you should be able to get the answer in a jiffy, viz.

Whether the question is P(1st ball is white) or P(last ball is white) or anything in the middle,

$$Pr =\frac{W}{W+B}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you stick a number to each ball from 1 to W+B, white balls sorted first, then you have (W+B)! equally likely possible sequence of outcomes. Now, if you write all the permutations in a column, you only need to find ones with a white ball at the end. The number of permutations ,with ball 1 at the end, is (W+B-1)!. The same is applied to other white balls and we get W(W+B-1)! permutations with a white ball at the end. Using the fact that all permutations are equally likely, we divide the number of desired outcomes (a white ball at the end) by the total number of permutations to get W/(W+B) which is as if we wanted to solve the problem: "find the probability of the first ball to be white".

Comment: i agree but in this case we could probably just skip to the last line

Answer (score 0):

Consider the permutation of the ball, by symmetry the probability of choosing white ball as the last ball is the same as choosing the white ball as the first ball.

Thus P=$W\over {W+B}$